# Wooden camping utensils?

Tags: woodworking, sculpting

Ozark Trail has a set of camping utensils. Now my question is how might it be duplicated in wood by a wittler? If your not sure what I’m talking about check out the name @ Amazon.com
[image: www.amazon.com]
Here’s a better picture as the actual items came
[image]

Comment: This question is quite broad and would be greatly improved if you narrowed it down somewhat; I'd suggest you pick a specific set of utensils  - or better yet a single one - along with pictures.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a spoon, fork & a knife. As for pictures, I’m not sure how to put them up from the website myself, sorry.

Comment: There's a button in the editor; just find the URL of the image you want to include and click on the right icon.

Comment: I just did @walrus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wittling a spoon or butter knife is not that difficult, but a 5 prong fork might be a challenge.  A two or three prong design would probably be easier.

As for "duplicating" the particular style and design of the Ozark Trail products, that would depend on the skill of the wittler.  The products that I have seen are plastic and factory smooth.  Personally, if I went to the trouble of hand crafting a set of cutlery, I would want it to look a little rough as that adds a little character to the result.